# Convergence of Nth order Householder Method for Polynomial Root Finding

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have a well behaved sixth order polynomial with at least two real roots.  All real roots are positive.  I wish to find the first root from zero using the householder method in closed form.

$$ f(x)=k_0-k_1x+k_2x^2 -k_3x^3+k_4 x^4 - k_5 x^5+k_6x^6 $$

The nth order householder method step towards the root (from the origin) is:
$$ x(n) = n \frac{(1/f(x))^{(n-1)}}{(1/f(x))^{(n)}}\biggr\rvert_{x=0}$$

Here, $g(x)^{(n)}$ is the nth derivative of g with respect to x.  Under the right conditions, this formula converges to the root with order n+1.  For my specific application, as I increase n, my resulting value gets closer and closer to the root.

My question is: Given, the above polynomial form (e.g. derivatives above order 6 are zero), is there a formula for the convergence of this householder step that can simply be written down in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial as n goes to infinity?

Comment: I am not sure to properly understand. Are you looking for the formula of $x_1$ ?

Comment: I'm looking for the limit of x(n) as n goes to infinity.  In practice, it seems to converge to the closest zero of the function as n gets larger and larger.  Is there a way of just writing down what this series converges to for a sixth order polynomial?